# converting offset notation to pointer arithmetic in 2d arrays c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, pointer-arithmetic

So I am attempting to complete an assignment using 2d pointer arrays. I was going through the process when I realized that was one of the requirements was that I was supposed to use pointer arithmetic, but instead I have been using offset notation. So my question for you guys is what is the best method of converting my offset notation into pointer arithmetic without completely rewriting the program???   Also when   transversing through my 2d array what parameters do I call for my outofbounds function in order for it to properly work? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

```
    //move through string by parsing  to insert each char into array element position

void rules(char** boardArr,int  &rows, fstream inFile, string &line, int &cols)
{
    char* pos;
    char ncount;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) //rows
    {
        getline(inFile, line);

        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) //cols
        {
            *(*(boardArr + i )+ j) == pos;//parsing string into bArr

            //neighbor check nested for organism
            pos  = *(*(boardArr + i)+ j);//position of index within
            if(*(*(boardArr + i+1)+ j)=='*')//checking pos to the right of pos index
            {
                //outofbounds()
                ncount++;
            }
            if(*(*(boardArr + i-1)+ j)=='*')//checking pos to the left of pos index
            {
                //outofbounds()
                ncount++;
            }
            if(*(*(boardArr + i)+ j+1)=='*')//checking pos to the above of pos index
            {
                //outofbounds()
                ncount++;
            }
            if(*(*(boardArr + i+1)+ j+1)=='*')//checking pos to the above and to the right of pos index
            {
                //outofbounds()
                ncount++;
            }
            if(*(*(boardArr + i-1)+ j+1)=='*')//checking pos above and to the  left of pos index
            {
                //outofbounds()
                ncount++;
            }
            if(*(*(boardArr + i-1)+ j-1)=='*')//checking pos below and to the left of pos index
            {
                //outofbounds()
                ncount++;
            }
            if(*(*(boardArr + i-1)+ j)=='*')//checking pos below of pos index
            {
                //outofbounds()
                ncount++;
            }
            if(*(*(boardArr + i-1)+ j+1)=='*')//checking pos below and to the right of pos index
            {
                //outofbounds()
                ncount++;
            }
            //row[i, row[i]-1])
            //cout<<*(*(boardArr + i)+ j);//assigning position to check for neighbors

        }



    }

//how to move through 2d array pointer arithmetic style

//boardArr[rows][cols] == *(*(boardArr + rows)+ cols)

//keep relationship between the numbers
//*(())
//If a cell contains an organism and has fewer than 2 neighbors, the organism dies of loneliness.
//A neighbor is an organism in one of the 8 spots (or fewer if on the edge) around a cell
//If a cell contains an organism and has more than 3 neighbors, it dies from overcrowding.
// If an empty location has exactly three neighbors, an organism is born in that location.
//returns nothing
}
bool  outofbounds( int &rows, int &cols, int i, int j)
{
    if((i >0 && i< rows)  && (j < cols && j > 0))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: When `i == 0`, what happens with `*(boardArr + i-1)`? Or when `i == rows - 1` and you have `*(boardArr + i+1)`? Same thing with `j` of course.

Comment: When i ==0, *(boardArr + i -1) is supposed to shift to the left/previous index address and check to see if it has an *. As its checking I pass my outofbounds function(should remain it to inbounds) to see if it should even use the information or not before moving to the next location within the index

Comment: why not use `boardArr[i][j]` instead of `*(*(boardArr + i)+ j)` ?

Comment: If `i == 0` then `*(boardArr + i - 1)` will be `*(boardArr + 0 - 1)` which is `*(boardArr - 1)` which is equal to `boardArr[-1]`. That's out of bounds, and in C++ indexing out of bounds leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You should *never* go out of bounds when indexing arrays or memory. And if `i == rows - 1` thne you go one out of bounds in the *other* direction with `*(boardArr + i + 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are no reasons to use pointer arithmetics for such simple operations.

Just use `arr[i][j]` to read/write data.

Also you should check for bounds before any read/write operations to the memory. It is dangerous and may crash your program.

Here is my version of How I'll implement such stuff.

```
#include <iostream>


/* it is good practice to move functions with special context to classes */
class SafeCharMatrix
{

private:

    /* your board */
    /* `char const* const*` provides that nobody can change data */
    char const* const* _ptr;
    int _rows;
    int _cols;

public:

    SafeCharMatrix(char const* const* ptr, int rows, int cols) :
        _ptr(ptr), _rows(rows), _cols(cols)
    {}

    /* valid check bounds algorithm */
    bool CheckBounds(int x, int y) const
    {
        if (x < 0 || x >= _cols)
            return false;

        if (y < 0 || y >= _rows)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    bool CheckCharSafe(int x, int y, char c) const
    {
        /* check bounds before read/write acces to memory */
        if (!CheckBounds(x, y))
            return false;

        return _ptr[x][y] == c;
    }

    int CountNeighborsSafe(int x, int y, char c) const
    {
        int count = 0;

        count += CheckCharSafe(x - 1, y - 1, c) ? 1 : 0;
        count += CheckCharSafe(x - 1, y    , c) ? 1 : 0;
        count += CheckCharSafe(x - 1, y + 1, c) ? 1 : 0;
        count += CheckCharSafe(x    , y - 1, c) ? 1 : 0;
        /* ignore center (x, y) */
        count += CheckCharSafe(x    , y + 1, c) ? 1 : 0;
        count += CheckCharSafe(x + 1, y - 1, c) ? 1 : 0;
        count += CheckCharSafe(x + 1, y    , c) ? 1 : 0;
        count += CheckCharSafe(x + 1, y + 1, c) ? 1 : 0;

        return count;
    }

};


/* fill you board before this */
void rules(char const* const* boardArr, int rows, int cols)
{
    SafeCharMatrix matrix(boardArr, rows, cols);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) /* y axis */
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) /* x axis */
        {
            int countOfNeighbors = matrix.CountNeighborsSafe(j, i, '*');

            /* do whatever you want */

            std::cout
                << "x: " << j << ", "
                << "y: " << i << ", "
                << "count: " << countOfNeighbors << "\n";
        }
    }
}


/* just example of how it can works */
int main()
{
    char r1[3] = {  0 ,  0 , '*'};
    char r2[3] = {  0 ,  0 ,  0 };
    char r3[3] = { '*',  0 ,  0 };

    char* m[3];
    m[0] = r1;
    m[1] = r2;
    m[2] = r3;

    rules(m, 3, 3);
}
```

**Edit:**

Don't pass simple arguments like `int` numbers by reference: `int &row`. They are to small and compiler can pack them in just one processor register.